# Multiple login providers for the same user?

Tags: meteor

I have just glanced over the MongoDB collection for users and it seems to allow multiple login providers for a single user. From what I see, everything seems to be "there": Multiple services, different resume tokens ...

But is there currently a documented way to "associate" a new login provider with an existing user? I couldn't find anything in the [official Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) :(

Or is there anything preventing this in the collection "schema"? Just in case, here is how it looks for a single user using the "password" login service.

```
{
    "createdAt" : 123456,
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "srp" : {
                "identity" : "XXX",
                "salt" : "XXX",
                "verifier" : "XXX"
            }
        },
            "resume" : {
                "loginTokens" : [
                    {
                        "token" : "XXX",
                        "when" : 123456
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
   "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "foo@example.org",
            "verified" : false
        }
   ],
   "_id" : "7f98645e-df24-4015-8075-2463c6c8cfc5"
}
```

Comment: The answer I gave on this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576532/194957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of meteor (0.8.0.3) it is not possible to make use of multiple login providers out of the box. But there is [package on athmosphere which allows this](http://atmospherejs.com/package/link-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but from what I know you can login the user with password, and then call `Meteor.loginWithFacebook`, for example, while the user is logged in.  This should add the Facebook information to the current user's data.

Comment: For some reason my app currently refuses to use any third party service provider, I will get back to your answer once I fixed that.

Comment: It seems that calling the `loginWithService` functions somehow confuses Meteor, as my login issues seem to be somehow related to this.

Comment: An easy way to troubleshoot this would be to create an entirely new app, try just the minimal amount of code and packages (i.e. `accounts-ui`, `accounts-password`, and `accounts-someprovider`).  If this doesn't work, try installing Meteor on another computer and do the same.

Comment: Calling loginWith* for a currently logged in user will not add the service information to the current user's data.  Instead, it will create a new user. I've verified this behavior with 0.6.5.